# Retrieving file names out of a multi-file upload control with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The HTML is:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload" id="id_upload" />
```

If I load up three files, `document.getElementById("id_upload").value` only returns a single file name and not an array of three names or comma separated string of three names. Same story with jQuery val(). Is there a way to get the whole list?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [the `.files` property](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-files) of that element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("id_upload");
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elem.files.length; ++ i) {
   names.push(elem.files[i].name);
}
```

Reference:

- [*Input.multiple — MDC*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.multiple)
- [*File — MDC*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File)