# Get input type="file" value when it has multiple files selected

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving file names out of a multi-file upload control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript)

From HTML5 input type="file" allows users to choose multiple files by adding the multiple="multiple" :

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

My question is: how can I get the value of that input? When using the .value it only returns the filename of the first file selected, but when choosing more than one I am not able to view the other ones.

What I have:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="alert(this.value)"
     onmouseout="alert(this.value) />
```

which as I told you, is only showing the name of one of the selected files.

NOTE: *I don't want to edit the value (I know that is not possible) only the name of the files*

Thanks!

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The files selected are stored in an array: `[input].files`

For example, you can access the items

```
// assuming there is a file input with the ID `my-input`...
var files = document.getElementById("my-input").files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 alert(files[i].name);
}
```

For jQuery-comfortable people, it's similarly easy

```
// assuming there is a file input with the ID `my-input`...
var files = $("#my-input")[0].files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 alert(files[i].name);
}
```

Comment: the files property of the file input is undefined on ie, though works just fine on other browsers. do you know any way to go around this?

Comment: `files[i]` is undefined in IE9. Can you give solution on how to get this work in IE9 ?

Comment: @OO7 IE9 doesn't support multiple input file. It is IE10+ only.

Comment: `name` is without path, what property is for full path?

Answer (score 12):

You [use `input.files` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications#Selecting_files_using_HTML). It's a collection of [File objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) and each file has a `name` property:

```
onmouseout="for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) alert(this.files[i].name);"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly the same as freedompeace answer (name or fileName both work) but he answered first and I cannot set two answers as accepted, +1 to your answer anyway

Comment: Actually, he answered without a proper code example first and edited his post after I sent mine. But - doesn't really matter. :)