# How can we upload multiple html files and replace the text inside and get the output html pages with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

From following code it accepts Single File and process it & display output.but can it be possible to accept multiple files and process & then return output.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>  
<body>
    <div>
       <label for="text">Choose file</label>
       <input id="text" type="file" name="photo">
    </div>
    <textarea id="finalHTML" style="height:200px;width:80%">

    </textarea><br/>


<button id="save">Save</button>
<script>

$('input').change(function(){
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    selectedImage = e.target.result;
    var rawData = reader.result;
    console.log(rawData);


    var array = {
        '<code CLASS="java">j</code>':'&#8660;', 
        '<code CLASS="bold">C</code>':'<b>C</b>',
        '<code CLASS="italic">g</code>':'&#156;',
        '<code CLASS="underline">i</code>':'&#126;',

    }

    var originalText = rawData.toString();
    var finalText = originalText;

    for (var val in array)
       finalText = finalText.replace(new RegExp(val, "g"), array[val]);

    console.log(finalText);

    $('#finalHTML').text(finalText);


  };

  reader.readAsBinaryString(this.files[0]);
 //reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);


  }
});

var button2 = document.getElementById('save');
button2.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);

function saveTextAsFile()
{
  var textToWrite = $('#finalHTML').text();
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "sample1.html"/*Your file name*/;

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null)
{
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
}
else
{
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
    // before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

   downloadLink.click();
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to accept multiple files and process on it,and return Output.
Any one can help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

You used input type 'file' there is an attribute multiple ="multiple" which allows you to select multiple file at once. How to handle those files using JavaScript? you can look at this link ...[Multiple-files-selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023457/get-input-type-file-value-when-it-has-multiple-files-selected)

try this and look at the for loop block... I'm not tasted it...

```
$('input').change(function(){
for(var i = 0; i<= files.length; i++){
  if (this.files && this.files[i]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
console.log(e);
selectedImage = e.target.result;
var rawData = reader.result;
console.log(rawData);


  var array = {
    '<code CLASS="java">j</code>':'&#8660;', 
    '<code CLASS="bold">C</code>':'<b>C</b>',
    '<code CLASS="italic">g</code>':'&#156;',
    '<code CLASS="underline">i</code>':'&#126;',

}

var originalText = rawData.toString();
var finalText = originalText;

for (var val in array)
   finalText = finalText.replace(new RegExp(val, "g"), array[val]);

console.log(finalText);

$('#finalHTML').text(finalText);


  };

  reader.readAsBinaryString(this.files[i]);
 //reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);


  }
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,But with this can i process, same as like with single file.

Comment: Its Selecting multiple files,but not able to get result.

Comment: Can you see my Fiddle     http://jsfiddle.net/yk6Tq/30/

i have updated your code,but not able to get result,so can you guide me,how to get result, with fiddle example