# jQuery : input multiple values

Tags: jquery, html, input, multifile-uploader

How to get a value from `<input type="file" name="attach_1" multiple>` using jQuery?

I did try `$('input').val()`, but when you use 2+ files it sends back just first one.

Comment: you loop through them using for loop

Comment: `var file = $('#input')[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
  console.log("file_" + i, file[i]);
}` try this way

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023457/get-input-type-file-value-when-it-has-multiple-files-selected

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#input').change(function(e) {
  var file = $('#input')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    console.log("file_" + i, file[i].name);



  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="input" name="input" multiple="">
```

Try this way