# Multiple Files check extension is Pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can we get multiple uploaded files has pdf if yes then enable Div

**case 1:** when I am trying to upload pdf file pdf checkbox is enabled
[image]

**Case 2:** upload docx or any other file checkbox gets hides 
[image: ente3:mage description here]

**Case 3:** When trying to upload different files such as txt, docx, pdf it is not showing checkbox
[image]

Please suggest how can we check extensions for multiple uploaded files and if there is pdf extension show checkbox div.

```
if (extn == 'pdf' || extn=='PDF') {
  $('#<%=chkAddPdfPassword.ClientID%>').removeAttr('checked');
  $("#chkPdf").show();
} else {
   $("#chkPdf").hide();
   $("#divPasswordField").hide();
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you have written in JavaScript will only check for single file. What you need to do is first check if has users selected a single file or multiple. If single, add your piece of logic in if block and in else block write another set of code that will iterate all upload file and check there extension is PDF or not. If found, show checkbox else hide.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal do yo have any example or snippet for this

Comment: Have a look. Might this help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023457/get-input-type-file-value-when-it-has-multiple-files-selected

Comment: Thanks mate but the solution is much extended... check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            var files = $('#<%=uploadFile.ClientID %>')[0].files; 
                            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
                                var a = checkFileExtension(files[i].name); 
                                if ((a == "pdf") || (typeof a  !== "undefined")) {
                                    console.log('check pdf');
                                $("#chkPdf").show();  
                                break;
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#chkPdf").hide();
                                }
                            }

            function checkFileExtension(file) {
                        var extension = file.substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
                        var fileExtn;
                        switch (extension) {
                            case 'pdf':
                                console.log('was pdf');
                                fileExtn = 'pdf';
                                break;
                            default:
                                console.log('who knows');
                                fileExtn = 'default';
                        }
                        return fileExtn;
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
  var files = $('#<%=uploadFile.ClientID %>')[0].files;

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {


                    var a = openFile(files[i].name);

                    if ((a == "pdf") || (typeof a  !== "undefined")) {
                        console.log('check pdf');
                    $("#chkPdf").show();  
                    break;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#chkPdf").hide();
                        $("#divPasswordField").hide();
                    }
                }

function openFile(file) {
            var extension = file.substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
            var fileExtn;
            switch (extension) {
                case 'jpg':
                case 'png':
                case 'txt':
                    console.log('was txt');  // There's was a typo in the example where
                    break;                         // the alert ended with pdf instead of gif.
                case 'zip':
                case 'docx':
                    console.log('was docx');
                    break;
                case 'pdf':
                    console.log('was pdf');
                    fileExtn = 'pdf';
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('who knows');
                    fileExtn = 'default';
            }
            return fileExtn;
        };
```