# JQuery - get all fileNames inside input='file'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<input type="file" id="basicUploadFile" multiple="multiple">` and I want to get all file names inside this input. I've seen some example, but it gets only name of first file.

```
$ ('#basicUploadFile').live ('change', function () {
    alert($ ('#basicUploadFile').val());
});
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171013/javascript-get-number-of-files-and-their-filenames-from-input-multiple-elemen

Comment: Exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
var files = $('#basicUploadFile').prop("files")
```

`files` will be a FileList object.

```
var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });
```

Now `names` is an array of strings (file names)

[FileAPI reference](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/)
[files property reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-files)

Comment: Good demonstration of the `.prop()` and `$.map()` methods that I wasn't aware of. :)

Comment: Yes, the support for the multiple attribute only appeared in IE10.

Comment: Use `if (window.File && window.FileList)` to check browser support

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898745/how-to-get-the-filename-in-javascript-from-input-file-tag .... pls help @wrock

Answer (score 12):

## [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r64uV/1/)

---

You can still access the files as a `FileList` collection without the need for over-using `jQuery`. I've created a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r64uV/1/) demonstrating how to get the information out of the input using the `FileList` and `File` objects. Here is a snippet:

```
$('#basicUploadFile').live('change', function ()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++)
    {
        alert(this.files[i].name);
        alert(this.files.item(i).name); // alternatively
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please explain a little why use of "this" instead of "$(this)"

Comment: `$(this)` would simply provide us with a jQuery wrapper for the object `this`, which in some instances would be helpful as it would expose certain methods, however in this case it's unnecessary.

Comment: this does not work in IE - IE does not allow you access to the list of files.

Comment: @Oddman, that's partially correct; multiple file upload is only supported in IE10, http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms

Comment: We've tested it extensively on our own browsers at work, and could not access the files property in any of the IE browsers :(

Comment: @Oddman, Hmm interesting, you could try using `this.files.item(i).name` instead.

Comment: @Richard - it's a little hard to access the item method if the files property isn't available ;)

Comment: @Oddman haha, pardon my assumptions, I thought it might've been a different structure rather than `undefined`. Sadly it turns out that the property isn't supported in either IE or Opera. http://help.dottoro.com/ljxenmhs.php [Update] Although this is conflicting, I'm so confused, lol. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh772307(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I used this to show in console all files name:

```
var input_file = $("#input_file");
input_file.on("change", function () {
     var files = input_file.prop("files")
     var names = $.map(files, function (val) { return val.name; });
     $.each(names, function (i, name) {
          console.log(name);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="selectAttachment" id="selectAttachment" type="file" multiple="multiple">
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="uploadAttachment()" type="submit">Upload</button>


function uploadAttachment() {
                debugger;
                var files = $('#selectAttachment').prop('files');
                var names = $.map(files, function (val) { return val.name; });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the prototype of **File Object** (for example `File.prototype.toJSON`), and you can access the FileList of `<input ..>`:

```
<input id="myFile" type="file">
```

```
 var file = document.getElementById('fileItem').files[0];
```

For more information check this documentation:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#Using_the_file_list

#### check this simple example:

```js
File.prototype.toJSON = function() {
 return {
  'lastModified'     : this.lastModified,
  'lastModifiedDate' : this.lastModifiedDate,
  'name'             : this.name,
  'size'             : this.size,
  'type'             : this.type 
 };
}

function getFiles() {
    var files = document.getElementById('myFiles').files;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<h1>result</h1>'
      + JSON.stringify(files);
}
```

```html
<input id="myFiles" type="file" multiple onchange="getFiles()" />
<pre id='result'></pre>
```

Good Luck!