# How to get the filename from file input type with jquery without form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the filename of a file user selected when a user clicks on a button it is not a submit button. I have tried many of the solutions given on stackoverflow but it does not work i have id of the field but it does not give the name of the file.

Below is my code:

```
function Data(a)
{   
var ext = $('#fieldid_'+a).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
.......

<input type="file" name="save_<?=$row1['id']?>" id="fieldid_<?=$row1['id']?>" /> 
<input type="button" id="submit_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="Upload File" onclick = "return Data(<?=$row1['id']?>)"/>
```

Comment: What does it give you? Pop removes the last element from the array so you are grabbing the extension of the file.

Comment: @epascarello blank value, i have also checked it with $('#fieldid_'+a).val() but the same blank value is the output.

Comment: So I ran the code with no issues, it returns the extension. So time to debug. What does `console.log( $('#fieldid_'+a));` return? My guess it is empty meaning it is not finding the element.

Comment: Please put the generated source code and not the php mark up in your question. There is something wrong with selecting the element.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script to get the file name:
Reference Link:[Use jQuery to get the file input's selected filename without the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365858/use-jquery-to-get-the-file-inputs-selected-filename-without-the-path)

```
jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name

(OR)

$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name
```

For more than on file:

```
var all_files = jQuery('input[type=file]');
var paths_arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<all_files.length;i++){
paths_arr.push(all_files[i].files[0].name);
} 
 paths_arr[0] = first file name
 paths_arr[1] = second file name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is giving me the name of file only of the first file control and i want the name of file which i pass as an id

Comment: var all_files = jQuery('input[type=file]');
var paths_arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<all_files.length;i++){
paths_arr.push(all_files[i].files[0].name); you can access the file names like all_files[0] = first file,all_files[1]  second file
} @user3653474

Answer (score 0):

Files is the **FileList** object & names is an **Array** of strings (file names)

```
$( "#buttonid_1" ).click(function(){
    var files = $('#fieldid_1').prop("files");
    var names = $.map(files, function(val){
        return val.name;
    });
    console.log(names[0]);
})
```

*Reference:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703223/3119231

*Example:* http://jsfiddle.net/ndfn782o/1/

EDIT: ***tested && 110% working***

Comment: It is giving me following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: 1. Did you changed the id of save_1 ? 2. Are you sure the error appears here? :D

Comment: u are getting it on change event of a file but i want it on a button click.

Comment: In jsfiddle it is working but in my browser it is giving error message in the console uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('fileInputId').files[0].name
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/romko/4z6pnxt9/)

Comment: This didn't work. It is giving following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

Comment: "How to get the filename from file input type with jquery without form submit"