# Preview name of file before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a list of file names that I will upload in the list_file div before uploading, is there a reference to that?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="name_file">
    <div id="list_file"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your problem may have been resolved at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703102/jquery-get-all-filenames-inside-input-file/34302309

Comment: @DoTrungDuc thank you for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input should be assigned `multiple` attribute to allow choose more than one file.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple id="files" name="name_file">
    <div id="list_file"></div>
 </form>
```

Later on, JavaScript code is:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('files');
var listFile = document.getElementById('list_file');

fileInput.onchange = function () {
  var files = Array.from(this.files);
  files = files.map(file => file.name);
  listFile.innerHTML = files.join('<br/>');
}
```

Comment: okay i will try it