# jQuery and input[type=file][multiple=multiple] values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, there is a field:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" class="multiupload" />
```

How can I acces all the files list when multiple files have selected?

`$('.multiupload').val()` returns only first file name. I trying to do this in Google Chrome.

Comment: Vanilla JavaScript has to be used: `$('.multiupload')[0].files[i].name` (where `i` = index of file, 0, 1, 2, ...).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving file names out of a multi-file upload control with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript)

Comment: Can you post your code on `http://jsfiddle.net/`?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is really duplicates that. That question has the workable example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.multiupload').map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
});
```

***Update:*** For using `multiple` attribute for one input filed, there is `files` property you could get.

```
$.map($('.multiupload').get(0).files, function(file) {
  return file.name;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works? He has **one** `input[type=file]` with the `multiple` attribute. Your code iterates over multiple *elements*.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Doesn't he want multiple values?

Comment: @xdazz: Yes, but in a *single* input field, not with multiple fields. I.e. similar to what `<select multiple>` does.

Comment: I tried with ur code, but its not working, selected 3 files, but getting alert for first file, http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/EXann/

Comment: @xdazz Rob W's link gives the answer, check this http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/EXann/1/

Comment: @ThiefMaster You're right, I missed the `multiple`, updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works. This example is works too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript Thank you!