# Get all values of multiple file select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving file names out of a multi-file upload control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript)

Got this:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" multiple="multiple" />
```

Using this in jQuery:

```
$("input[name=file1]").change(function() {
    $("input[name=file]").val($("input[name=file1]").val());
});
```

Now my problem is this: It only gives the first selected file, I would like to have them all... How to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: @bvl Make sure click the checkmark next to the correct answer, or eventually people will stop helping you.  Not barking, just informing :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Although I linked to a possible dupe in the comments, it's a pure JavaScript solution. Here's a jQuery version if you like: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gSBCd/)**

```
$("input[name=file1]").change(function() {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
        names.push($(this).get(0).files[i].name);
    }
    $("input[name=file]").val(names);
});​
```

Comment: `$('#multiFileSelector').files` give you an array of `File`s

Comment: or `$('#multiFileSelector')[0].files`

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the 'files' property, which returns a filelist:

```
var ele = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
var result = ele.files;
```

[Here is the Fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/BaGQt/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.length()` to get the number of files then use a while statement to do the same for all files, increasing the count by 1 each time :)

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right. So I should use `$("input[name=file1]").length`? this also gives me 1 as an output.

Comment: Yes, so for example
i=0;
while (i<=$("input[name=file1]").length){
//what to do to each file
i++;
}