# How to get all the values of input file array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

i have an input array to select multiple files.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple='multiple'/>
<div id='my_div'>Filenames</div>
```

How do i get the filenames using jquery?
For text types, the map function works

```
var values=$("input[name='text_string[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Is there any way to get filenames on clicking div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all values of multiple file select with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652955/get-all-values-of-multiple-file-select-with-jquery)

Comment: just change your selector to `$("input[type='file']")`

Comment: it gives only the first fiename

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `files` array of the control and then `map()` to create an array of the individual file names, something like this:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var filenames = Array.from(this.files).map(function(f) {
    return f.name;
  });
  console.log(filenames);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple='multiple' />
```

Comment: Instead of input change, can i get the value on a div or button click?

Comment: Absolutely, I just used the change handler as an example. You can reference the element in any way you like

Comment: ok. it works. but it wont help me. because... first i select 2 images and on second time i select another 2 images first two gets cleared. so i used to append input type file with different id each time. so i want to fetch all image names from input type files from the name files[]. so finally i will get 4 images.