# Jquery in rails app is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that allows users to attach multiple files and detach files using jquery. However, the problem is you can select multiple files but only the last file selected gets uploaded. Not all files that were selected. Think it's something with my javascript code. 
below is an image of what i am talking about
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BvTk.png)

zen_support/zen_upload.js

```
$(function() {
  files = void 0;
  setRemove = void 0;
  uploadfile = void 0;
  files = [];
  $('#upload_button').click(function(event) {
    return $('#file_input').trigger('click');
  });
  $('#file_input').change(function(event) {
    var file;
    file = void 0;
    file = event.target.files[0];
    files.push(file);
    return uploadfile(files.length - 1, file);
  });
  uploadfile = function(index, file) {
    var fileitem, formData;
    fileitem = void 0;
    formData = void 0;
    formData = new FormData;
    formData.append('file', file);
    fileitem = '<li class=\'file-item success\'> <div class=\'active\'> <span class=\'remove\'>×</span> <span>' + file.name + '</span> </div> <div class=\'lds-ellipsis\'><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div> </li>';
    $('#filelist').append(fileitem);
    return setRemove();
  };
  return setRemove = function() {
    $('.remove').unbind();
    return $('.remove').click(function() {
      var index;
      index = void 0;
      index = $(this).parent().parent().index();
      files.splice(index, 1);
      return $('.file-item').eq(index).remove();
    });
  };
});
```

_edit.html.haml

```
= render 'show'
= javascript_include_tag "zen_support/zen_upload.js"
.row
  .col-12
    %ZenForm{ path: zen_support_urls.ticket_path, id: @zendesk_ticket.id, method: :put, :multipart => true, data: { remote: true } }
      .row
        .col-md-4
          %button.fileUpload.btn.btn-default#upload_button{type: "button"}
            Attach File
            %input.upload#file_input{:name => "attachments[]",  multiple: true, :type => "file"}
        .col-md-8
          %ul#filelist
          - @zendesk_ticket.comments.each do | comment |
            = render "files", comment: comment
      %ZenTextArea#comment{ label: "Comments", placeholder: "Add any comments you think will help us address your issue.", error: @zendesk_ticket.errors&.dig(:comment) }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere on your code you loop over all selected files. I see something like `e.target.files[0]`, you are calling the `uploadFile` function once with only one file.

Comment: how would you change the code to loop through all selected files. Sorry new to jquery

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652955/get-all-values-of-multiple-file-select-with-jquery