# How to use input file twice

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have  `<input type="file" name="attach" multiple>`, and I need to use this 2 or more times as multiple. What I mean, what I need:

1. First click I choose 2 files:

> file1.png
>
> file2.png

2. Second click I choose 3 files:

> file3.png
>
> file4.png
>
> file5.png

and I need 5 files.

But when I do second click I have just last 3.

Comment: possible this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript

Comment: Why don't you select 5 file in one time and use them accordingly on server side

Comment: @SunilPachlangia I will be, but my client no..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one i approach , i can suggest is when user selects files you can replace previous `<input type="file"....>` with new having same name attribute.

Now user will again select few files and submit. you will get both multiple files at server side because name attribute is same for both input element.

```
<div id="parent">
     <input type="file" name="attach[]" onchange="append_new_input_element(this)" multiple>
</div>
```

Add following function

```
function append_new_input_element(this){
parent_div = document.getElementById("parent");
this.style.display = "none";
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
input.name = "attach[]";             

input.setAttribute("onchange","append_new_input_element(this)");              
parent_div.appendChild(input);

}
```

Or i will suggest to use dropzone for this purpose.
[dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Comment: i need as attach for email, so dropzone is not good. I don\`t need save it on server.

if i will be have a lot of inputs, it will be wissible in `$_FILES`?

Comment: Try above script , multiple files should be visible in $_FILES