# Accessing File from multiple/Different File INPUTS to JS Var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

[Screenshot of choosing files from different file inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZudaF.png)

So as you can see I have multiple file inputs. It might look awkward but I have a reason.

I use this way to access the file in the usual way which is
`var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];`

but it gets the file only if I upload it to the first file input box is there any way I could access the other file input elements.

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving file names out of a multi-file upload control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the other DOM selecting methods like [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), and etc which can select more than one element at a time.

`querySelectorAll` for instance will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), an array like object containing all the selected elements. Then either iterate over that list or use direct access to get to the element.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]');
inputs.forEach(input=>{
  //deal with each input
  let file = input.files[0];
  //use file
});

//or if using older browser that doesn't have NodeList#forEach
for(let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  let file = inputs[i].files[0];
  //use file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `querySelectorAll` method because it returns the list of nodes and then you can iterate throw the list and get everything you want. `querySelector` method returns only the first appearance of the selector